# How do I properly determine if user is dragging my circle wheel slider Clockwise or Counter Clockwise using time?

Tags: java, android, computational-geometry

I have a custom view that is shaped like a clock. I have a slider image that a user can use to slide around the clock counter clockwise (CCW) or clockwise (CW) so they can select time. My custom view returns me a `time` of data type `String` in a `H:mm aa` format. e.g.: `1:34 AM`.

I'm currently able to determine a CW or CCW detection but it is not full proof as there is an issue when users slide past the 12:00 AM point.

My current logic for determining CW or CCW movement is:

1. Convert `time` into military time so I can store it as a `Date` object known as `mDate`.
2. Check if the last `timeToMil` is less than the current `mDate.getTime()`. If it is less, I assume it's CW, else it's CCW.
3. Store the current number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 into variable `timeToMil` so the next iteration can determine if the last point moved forward in time or moved backwards.

The issue though is if the users last time for example is 11:00 PM and moves the slider to 1:00AM. Going with #2 logic, this will detect it to be CCW which is incorrect.

```
if (timeToMil < mDate.getTime()) {
    cw = true; 
} else {
    cw = false;
}
```

I was wondering if there's a better approach than this? I've been looking at it for way too long that I don't think it's productive anymore and it would help to see some outside perspectives.

I was thinking about converting all the minutes into some sort of radians but I'm not sure if that effort is the way to go.

EDIT:
Adding Photo:

[image]

The Gray circle is the image that a user can drag along the red line either clockwise or counter clockwise. Sliding left is CCW, sliding it right is CW

Comment: can you provide a picture of the ui and how you want to use it. if it is a slider. which way is it sliding left = CW right = CCW. if they can just drag their finger 2d around the face of the watch then having a vector from the last position to the new one will help.

Comment: @mavriksc Hi, I've added a picture to help you visualize.

Comment: i would not have the view return a time. but angle and direction. typically you don't want the view to know or care about the type of data. this could be a volume knob or  anything. you could also keep track of how many times you complete a revolution.

Comment: I also wouldn't do it that way too, but my question wasn't about how I should have implemented the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h - hours [1,12]
m - minutes [0,59]

720 = 12*60 - minutes for full circle of hour hand

halfOfCircle = 360 = 720/2 - minutes for half-circle of hour hand

```
timePrev = timeNext
timeNext = (h%12)*60+m

if (abs(timePrev-timeNext)<halfOfCircle){
    if (timePrev<timeNext){
        return "CW"
    } else {
        return "CCW"
    }
} else {
    if (timeNext<halfOfCircle){
        return "CW"
    } else {
        return "CCW"
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have clarified that one revolution = 24 hours. Also what do you mean by `minutes for half-circle of hour hand` ?

Comment: Do you mean # of minutes in half a circle? which in my case would be 720 since i'm running 24 hours?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you mean "one revolution = 24 hours", than "minutes in half a circle = 720".

Comment: So then this wouldn't really work then right if my `h` would be `[0,23]`

Comment: Okay i tweaked it to work for my 24hr format and yes it worked. Instead of the formula you had for `timeNext`, I just took the minutes since I had the date object of the specific time. Applied the halfcircle to be 720 and then it worked. Your solution is fine for 12 hour format so I will still accept it.